# Configuring Civicrm For Organizational Membersship And Not Individual

Tags: civimember

I am trying to use Civicrm with wordpress to manage Organizations as Members NOT Individuals. But i discovered when i was testing that when I sign up for membership and i check the option I am Contributing on behalf of an organization that when i log in using the login details i created i see the dashboard of the individual and not the organization unless i login as the admin though.
How can i create a Sign up form such that the organization has its own username and password such that when i login i can see the dashboard of the organization

I am using Civicrm 4.6.8 with wordpress.